# disable specifict eslint rule reactjs

Tags: typescript, eslint

How can I disable the **no-unused-vars** rule only for the typescript interface?

```
export type IKeoTableColumn<T> = {
  id: T;
  align: 'left' | 'center' | 'right';
  label: string;
  minWidth: number;
  format?: (value: number) => string, <-------- warning here (value: number)
}[];
```

my eslintrc.json like

```
--- some code ---
"rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
}
```

please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration in your `.eslintrc` is wrong. You should turn off the base rule and only use the typescript extension like this:

```
"rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn",
}
```